# Best solution for open and edit .db files?

Tags: sqlite

I need a simple software for open and edit .db files

Comment: Can you add more details/requirements that would make a certain software the "best"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Database Browser](http://www.etl-tools.com/database-browser/overview.html):

- free
- Microsoft Windows
- portable version
- Works directly with Oracle, MS Sql Server, ODBC, MySql, OleDB, BDE, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS Sql Server Compact, Interbase and Firebird
- Execution history
- SQL Builder

[image]